# lateinit property exampleRepository has not been initialized

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin

I have class which has two methods, and I am trying to test these methods.  `class exampleClass(private val exampleRepository: ExampleRepository)` the class has repository as parameter, and when I try to add `lateinit var exampleRepository: ConfigRepository` in the test class I am getting error **lateinit property exampleRepository has not been initialized**. How can I initialized the repository?

Comment: You can find the solution here -> https://java.tutorialink.com/lateinit-property-mock-object-has-not-been-initialized/

Comment: `lateinit` means you're promising to set a value on that property before anything tries to read it, and you're not doing that. So you need to assign a `ConfigRepository` to it. Why does it have the same name as one of your constructor parameters? Which is a `val` anyway, meaning it's a property on the class too - are you sure you don't just want to use that? You might want to post your full code (the class and whatever uses that class) so people can see what you're trying to do